# How firm a bite should Ptitim (pearl couscous) have?

Tags: pasta

I've made Ptitim for my family a couple of times without any prior experience of how it should taste. After about 25 mins of simmering, the pearls remained quite firm (a little like pasta that needs a couple of minutes more). I wonder if this is correct, or if I should have continued simmering.

I used Ptitim with rather large pearls (spheres of about 5mm diameter). I used enough liquid that the pearls were still coated when I had stopped cooking.

The results were edible, even tasty. Still I wonder if the pearls should have been quite so chewy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used (since childhood) to eat ptitim that are only a little firmer than al dente. I've never had 5mm ones, though.

Comment: I wondered for a while whether the pearls would soften any further at all. I left the remaining Ptitim in the fridge over night and the following day the pearls were as soft as baked beans, which is a little too soft. I guess I'll have to experiment with cooking times.

Comment: Do you fry them before adding the water? Just curious. I always fry the dry ptitim in some oil or butter, occasionally with onions, and only then add water. I find it hard to treat it like regular pasta :)

Comment: Yes I did this and then added twice as much water (in volume) as Ptitim. I've seen other cooking suggestions where much more water is used, as when cooking pasta. I've not tried that yet, and perhaps I should.

Comment: I do it your way: only a little water, more like cooking rice I guess.